# How to customize system settings window

Tags: release-freya

I am using elementary OS freya. How to customize (add or remove) applications in system settings window.

For example,
Removing sound icon under hardware section in system settings.
Adding an application to system settings window .

**EDIT** :

I have considered the above two cases as examples. I found a similar link [is-it-possible-to-add-custom-items-to-system-settings-window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108060/is-it-possible-to-add-custom-items-to-system-settings-window)

Comment: May I ask why? You will probably not gain more than a MB of disk space and risk an unstable system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System Settings (code named Switchboard) is populated using extensions (called plugs). You cannot add an arbitrary app here. A Switchboard extension must be written.

To remove the sound plug, use the command:

```
sudo apt remove switchboard-plug-gcc-sound
```

Please be aware that some system components may depend on certain plugs to provide functionality. Generally, removing default plugs is not a good idea.

Comment: @Ravan elementary OS does not use GNOME Control Center. These directions do not apply.