# How do I remove item[duplcate] from system settings on elementary os?

Tags: settings

I am using elementary OS Freya, It works fine unitl yesterday I add a ubuntu deb link in sources.list, After I `apt-get update & apt-get dist-upgrade`, so, you can tell how silly I am, however, I want to remove the duplcate item in system-settings window.

Can any body help me please? (forgive my english sucks :-) )

[image: screenshot]
Here is a thread but not solve my Q.
[How to customize system settings window](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2660/how-to-customize-system-settings-window)

Comment: [edit] Q and add output of `nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and output of `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Thanks! I already  "rm  /etc/apt/sources.list", so the file is doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This morning, I did this:

```
dpkg -l | grep "network"
```

and terminal output like:

`ii  switchboard-plug-gcc-network     0.3.0~r29~ubuntu0.3.1                                   ii  switchboard-plug-networking      0.1+r175~daily~ubuntu0.3.1.1 ...`

and

```
sudo dpkg -r switchboard-plug-networking
```

and

problem solved!

thanks @Jeroen @Ravan

**btw,  How flag the question are solved ?**

Answer (score 0):

You have upgraded to the daily (beta) PPA. This can couse this kind of bugs. The only way to remove the double items it by eighter removing the old non-beta items or the new ones.

Comment: @pongChong You could accept one of our answers, that would help the statistics of this stack exchange site(as you can see on the side, only 75% is marked...)